# (Object doesn't support #inspect) for mailer Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailer

So I'm trying to create two emails. One is sent to a Restaurant when it has at least an order (orders_of_the_day), otherwise it sends the other ones (no_order_today).

The orders_of_the_day case works great. The second does not: It get the following error when I run `RestaurantMailer.no_order_today` in local:

> (Object doesn't support #inspect)

Here is my restaurant_mailer.rb file:

```
class RestaurantMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'noreply@takeameal.fr'

  def self.send_orders_of_the_day
    @restaurants = Restaurant.where(vacation_mode: false)
    @restaurants.each do |r|
      @meal = Meal.find_by(restaurant_id: r[:id], week_day: Date.today.cwday)
      @orders = Order.where("created_at >= :start_time and meal_id = :meal", start_time: DateTime.new(Date.today.year, Date.today.month, Date.today.day, 13, 0, 0).in_time_zone('Paris').prev_day, meal: @meal.id).order(:pick_up_time)
      if !@orders.empty?
        orders_of_the_day(r, 'À OUVRIR AVANT 11H30 : COMMANDES TAKE A MEAL ', @meal, @orders).deliver_now
      else
        no_order_today(r, 'Pas de commandes Take a Meal aujourd\'hui', @meal)
      end
    end
  end

  def orders_of_the_day(recipient, shift, meal, orders)
    @meal = meal
    unless @meal.nil?
      @orders = orders
      emails = [recipient[:email], recipient[:email2], recipient[:email3]].delete_if { |email| email.empty? }
      mail(to: emails, subject: shift)
    end
  end

  def no_order_today(recipient,shift, meal)
    @meal = meal
    emails = [recipient[:email], recipient[:email2], recipient[:email3]].delete_if { |email| email.empty? }
    mail(to: emails, subject: shift)
  end

end
```

Any idea on why I get this and how to solve it ?

Comment: You are not calling `deliver_now` in `no_order_today`

Comment: Indeed... I was actually testing it first in the console... Make sense now. Thank you very much for your help @PardeepDhingra !

Answer (score 2):

as @Pardeep Dhingra mentionned in the comments, I need to call `deliver_now` so that the mail get sent.

To run `RestaurantMailer.no_order_today(recipient, shift, meal)` in the console wont work either. So the right answer is:

- `RestaurantMailer.no_order_today(recipient, shift, meal).deliver_now`
  to test in the console
- `no_order_today(r, 'Pas de commandes Take a Meal aujourd\'hui',
  @meal).deliver_now` in my code.